# Populate Woocommerce SKU on wishlist

Tags: php, wordpress

I done a bunch of research and testing and can't seem to get the unique SKU from the product page to populate the wishlist.

I'm using YITH Woocommerce Wishlist and edited the wishlist.php file to include this code:

```
<?php if( get_option( 'yith_wcwl_stock_number_show' ) == 'yes' ) : ?>
                        <td class="product-stock-number">
                            <?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endif ?>
```

with this at the top:

```
global $product;
```

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_sku() on a non-object in /home2/cityrank/public_html/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/templates/wishlist.php on line 142

thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is the code for the price:

```
<?php if( get_option( 'yith_wcwl_price_show' ) == 'yes' ) : ?>
                        <td class="product-price">
                            <?php
                            if( $product_obj->price != '0' ) {
                                if( get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' ) == 'excl' )
                                    { echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price_html', woocommerce_price( $product_obj->get_price_excluding_tax() ), $values, '' ); }
                                else
                                    { echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price_html', woocommerce_price( $product_obj->get_price() ), $values, '' ); }
                            } else {
                                echo apply_filters( 'yith_free_text', __( 'Free!', 'yit' ) );
                            }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Just because you have $product at the top of the script doesn't mean a product is loaded. woocommerce only loads the product for specific pages (single-product for example) Check if is_product() is returning true or false?

Comment: Thanks skrilled. Where do I look for is_product()?

Comment: before the code you are running, maybe add something like <?php if(is_product()) die("THIS IS A PRODUCT"); ?> just to test that woocommerce is loading a a product into that view

Comment: I added that line of code and it didn't produce anything. I removed the get_sku() php just to test your script by itself. That removed the error message but I don't see "This is a product" anywhere.

Comment: there you go then, woocommerce is not loading a product into the $product variable. is this supposed to be a product page, or what page is it?

Comment: It's a wishlist page. There is a thumbnail of the product, a price and stock status all carried over. Above is the code for the price, which I assume uses a similar convention for SKU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you added today...

I would propose trying the following instead:

```
$product_obj->get_sku();
```

For this particular page it seems they are not loading the product into $product, but instead using $product_obj(ect)

Comment: Thanks skrilled! I'll give it a try and report back shortly.

Comment: That worked to ouput the SKU into the wishlist. Well done skrilled. It is still causing an issue in that since there is not user login it only loads the test product I had, no matter which browser I'm using or cache cleared. When I logged into the WP admin it then allowed me to successfully remove items and add others. As soon as I logged out it went right back to showing only the test product. Weird. Any ideas? Perhaps I need the 'global $product;' ?

Comment: Was this a plugin you got?

Comment: Yes, it's YITH Wishlist.

Comment: I think it's best if you create a new question since this one was answered, and then see if others can help you with your new issue. I'm really busy :p but I just try to give back to the community that once helped me when I can :)

Comment: I started the new question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669589/getting-woocommerce-sku-in-cart-and-wishlist)